# Website home page error in IE 9

Tags: c1-cms

I have developed a C1 V3.0 masterpage based simple website.

When I view the website it resolves correctly to the home page in any browser except IE 9.0.

It works with IE 8.0, Chrome and Firefox, and Tablets.

In IE 9.0 if I enter the URL of another page within the website it works fine, but the homepage tries to resolve to the PageTitle and gives a 404 error (File or Diretory not found.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be because you have browsed your site with your IE9 browser, before changing the URL schema to not include the title? I've experienced many times before that the browser caches the redirect-header, so because it once redirected from http://www.domain.com/ -> http://www.domain.com/SomePage it will keep doing it, even thought it yields in an invalid url.

Try clear all history and cache in your IE9 browser and see if that helps.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick.  Thank you Pauli.  I suspected it was a cache related issue, but didn't think of clearing the history.